# c# conditional & inclusive logic flow structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on an asp.net page and need to output html based on a numeric value.

The logic is thus:

If the ReferenceCount is greater than 13, then output a Div-1:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
```

If the ReferenceCount is greater than 16, then output a Div-1 and a Div-2:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("TShirt", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
```

If the ReferenceCount is greater than 17, then output a Div-1 and a Div-2 and a Div-3:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("TShirt", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("Banner", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
```

If the ReferenceCount is greater than 22, then output a Div-1 and a Div-2 and a Div-3 and a Div-4:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("TShirt", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("Banner", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
```

etc for a total of 27 more evaluations ....

Does anyone have any good ideas how to structure this logic flow as efficiently as possible?

I'd rather not have so many if statements, and I considered a Switch statement, which would allow you to fall through various Case tests, but you don't seem to be able to have expressions in the Case statements of Switches in C#.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have this pattern, you should abstract it away into something like this:

```
class TweetSetting
{
    public int MinReferenceCount { get; protected set; }
    public string ViewName { get; protected set; }

    public TweetSetting(int minReferenceCount, string viewName)
    {
        MinReferenceCount = minReferenceCount;
        ViewName = viewName;
    }
}

…

var settings =
    new[]
    {
        new TweetSetting(13, "Tweet"),
        new TweetSetting(16, "TShirt"),
        new TweetSetting(17, "Banner"),
        new TweetSetting(22, "Tweet")
    };

var referenceCount = …; // whatever

foreach (var setting in settings)
{
    if (referenceCount <= setting.MinReferenceCount)
        break;

    Html.RenderPartial(setting.ViewName, Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

This way, if something changes, you just modify `settings`. Even better: you could load it from a settings file and modifying wouldn't require changing the code at all.

Comment: Thanks. This is great.  But if there is a network issue, my Model.tweets might be null.  How can I handle this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If each statement is just adding an extra line, then I would do something like this

```
if (refcount > 13)
    Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
if (refcount > 16)
    Html.RenderPartial("TShirt", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
if (refcount > 17)
    Html.RenderPartial("Banner", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
if (refcount > 22)
    Html.RenderPartial("Tweet", Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault());
```

That way you aren't repeating yourself so much.

Comment: yeah, i think I was over thinking this.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd move `Model.tweets.FirstOrDefault()` out in front before the first condition into a variable that way you're not leaving yourself vulnerable to race conditions.  That way you aren't repeating yourself so much.  :)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I pasted that example in too quickly.  I actually wouldn't be passing tweets to each item.  I'd probably use different ViewModel classes for each group, so I can easily pass in extra data.